Error in creating new react app using create-react-app appname
Installing template dependencies using npm...
npm error code ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm error
npm error While resolving: notifyapp@0.1.0
npm error Found: react@19.0.0
npm error node_modules/react
npm error   react@"^19.0.0" from the root project
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peer react@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.4.0
npm error node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm error   @testing-library/react@"^13.0.0" from the root project
npm error
npm error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm error
npm error

give solution to reslove this

which command are you using for installing template dependencies? Share all details.

create-react-app is garbage, don't use it

@AmitVerma I have the same issue. "npx create-react-app myappname". Then got the similar error.

@test1229 have u tried the command with  --force or --legacy-peer-deps as mentioned in above error log ? It resolves many problems.

@AmitVerma the 2 flag both worked! BUT "--force" flag led to a lot of warns instead of error. Though "--legacy-peer-deps" flag silenced the error and got no warns, I wondered whether accepting an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution  would lead to any error in future. So, i wanted to know whether there is any more decent and reliable solution.

The release of React 19 has broken the dependency tree CRA is trying to create. It's no longer maintained, and this situation will only get worse - use e.g. Vite instead.

@AmitVerma I used the 2 flags but its still not working.

Consider switching to Vite.
Here's how to set up a new React project using Vite:
# Create new Vite project
npm create vite@latest my-react-app

# Navigate to project directory
cd my-react-app

# Install dependencies
npm install

# Start dev server
npm run dev

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/13717#issuecomment-2537222504

If you really need the lib @testing-library/react. You can install it with the command: npm i @testing-library/react.
PS: The @testing-library/react@13.4.0 requires react@"^18.0.0" and the create-react-app is using react 19

yarn create react-app my-app --template typescript


the first step is to locate your project folder
then run these commands one by one

npm uninstall react react-dom

then

npm install react@18 react-dom@18

then

npm install --no-audit --save @testing-library/jest-dom@^5.14.1 @testing-library/react@^13.0.0 @testing-library/user-event@^13.2.1 web-vitals@^2.1.0

then

npm start

or you can go with this YouTube link: https://youtu.be/mUlfo5ptm1o?si=hYHTwc7hApEXzPX5
